# preferredContentSize to change Window size doesn't work in osx 10.12.6

Tags: swift, macos, resize, nswindow

I have a `NSWindowController` with `NSViewController` as content view in it. which contains some text, which is dynamic. so if the text is more, I want to increase the height of my Window. which I could do using below code :

```
self.preferredContentSize = NSMakeSize(335, 120)
```

But the above `preferredContentsize` doesn't change window size for OSX 10.12.6.

It works properly for OSX 10.13.6 , 10.14

Answer (score 1):

```
self.view.window?.setContentSize(NSMakeSize(335, 120))
self.view.frame = NSRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 335, height: 120)
```

changing windowContentSize and View's Frame solved my issue.